# Add additional links to Unity Mail Notifier for Hotmail

Tags: unity, 18.04, mail

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm exploring new features. I have set up Unity Mail notifier but links can only be configured for 1 account, not for Hotmail and Gmail both. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

https://tari.in/www/software/unitymail/

[image]

Comment: Seems it's one for all, so you can only set up links for 1 or the other and not for each account. You can either go to Gmail or Hotmail, although you do get notifications for all Mail accounts. Maybe I will request Links for individual accounts on the Git Page.

Comment: Posted Issue on Site page....https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-mail/+question/668960